# Change system time using C or C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

How can I change the system time on Windows using C or C++?

I searched the Internet but I could not find it.

Follow this link : http://learnhacking.in/c-program-to-set-change-current-system-date/

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If this is what you want, I don't know how hard you looked. [SetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx). It also seems there's a local version.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, you can get time via the [GetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (along with a few different C/C++ standard library functions) and set the time via [SetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Note that you need certain privileges in Windows to alter the time, so if you do not have those privileges, then you need to get the Administrator to give you more rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by including the windows.h header and calling SetSystemTime(...) function.

Comment: @David, windows.h (or close enough, it's actually winbase.h).

Comment: @MrUniverse, That's where backticks come in useful.