# Windows equivalent function of clock_gettime/clock_settime?

Tags: c, linux, windows, time

I want to implement function `clock_gettime` and `clock_settime`.

"`clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, timespec)`" is equivalent to "`GetProcessTimes`".

but what is the equivalent function of "`clock_settime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, timespec)`" ?

I think "`SetSystemTime`" is equivalent to "`clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, timespec)`", but "`clock_settime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, timespec)`" is for counting from current process start, it's different from the `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change system time using C or C++ on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617393/change-system-time-using-c-or-c-on-windows)

Comment: AFAIK, SetSystemTime is for changing UTC time, but CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID is for counting time from current process start. it seems not the same thing.